# Joining very large datasets using hadoop map reduce

Tags: hadoop

What is the best approach to perform a join on 2 very large datasets using hadoop map reduce? Distributed cache or temporary storage like arraylists would not be able to store intermediate data since both data sets are quite large.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323544/configure-map-side-join-for-multiple-mappers-in-hadoop-map-reduce/

Comment: What exactly is expected is a single file output. So would have a single reducer in picture. The issue can be tackled with a  join query in Hive, but the situation here demands the need for a map reduce operation.

Comment: I don't know if I understood the problem properly. If you have to use a full map-reduce job to join your datasets(for some reasons) then it is trivial to do, but of course inefficient. Best way is to use a map-side join where there is just one phase - map. To get the details please visit Thomas link. To get very nice explanations look at "Hadoop the definitive guide" book, but there is no any code example. To get it look at "Pro Hadoop" book.