# Working with Hadoop with two datasets

Tags: hadoop

I'm working with Hadoop and try to make some interection function with two datasets what's the best scenario. I can load one into memory and then intersect in map function with other dataset but if dataset is too large for RAM memory it is not a solution, what are your thoughts?

---

Thanks for answers, I'll try out these to see what's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to maneuver Intersection in MapRed compared to the other family of platforms around the Hadoop API. Someone already mentioned Hive (super easy to do intersections if you have SQL background), but you may also consider:

- [PIG](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28inner%29)
- [Cascading](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.0/userguide/html/ch03s03.html#N2061A) (specifically CoGroup if Memory is a concern and HashJoin if it isn't)

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting them into the [`DistributedCache`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) - there's a nice illustrative example on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed Cache is good for small data set and may consider to cache in memory. If the data is large, distributed cache is not an option, as you mentioned.

Hadoop framework allows to sort on large data sets, however, you may have to follow number of steps and one of the requirements is that, the input data sets must be sorted before the join can be made. You may consider leveraging the Apache Hive for this. If Hive is ruled out, the steps mentioned in this link should help you get started for large data sets

[Configure Map Side join for multiple mappers in Hadoop Map/Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323544/configure-map-side-join-for-multiple-mappers-in-hadoop-map-reduce/)